# Interrupted downloads when downloading a file from Web Api (remote host closed error 0x800704CD)

Tags: exception, asp.net-web-api, download

I have read near 20 other posts about this particular error, but most seem to be issues with the code calling `Response.Close` or similar, which is not our case. I understand that this particular error means that *typically* a user browsed away from the web page or cancelled the request midway, but in our case we are getting this error without cancelling a request. I can observe the error just after a few seconds, the download just fails in the browser (both Chrome and IE, so it's not browser specific).

We have a web api controller that serves a file download.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Download()
{
    //
    // Enumerates a directory and returns a Read-only FileStream of the download
    var stream = dataProvider.GetServerVersionAssemblyStream(configuration.DownloadDirectory, configuration.ServerVersion);

    if (stream == null)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                        Content = new StreamContent(stream)
                    };

    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = $"{configuration.ServerVersion}.exe";
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;

    return response;
}
```

Is there something incorrect we are doing in our `Download` method, or is there something we need to tweak in IIS?

- This happens sporadically. I can't observe a pattern, it works sometimes and other times it fails repeatedly.
- The file download is about 150MB
- The download is initiated from a hyperlink on our web page, there is no special calling code
- The download is over HTTPS (HTTP is disabled)
- The Web Api is hosted on Azure
- It doesn't appear to be timing out, it can happen just after a second or two, so it's not hitting the default 30 second timeout values

I also noticed I can't seem to initiate multiple file downloads from the server at once, which is concerning. This needs to be able to serve 150+ businesses and multiple simultaneous downloads, so I'm concerned there is something we need to tweak in IIS or the Web Api.

Comment: Have you observed the memory ? is it increasing ? Or maybe open ports ? Are there many in the Wait Status?

Comment: Load of the server is very low - traffic being 1-2 hits an hour for the download, and available memory of the server is 3.5GB with 50% utilization even during the download. CPU utilization bumps up to 20% during the download. I recently fixed a bunch of memory leaks in the code, which are all resolved now, but the problem still persists. This web api is the only application/service on the server other than the SQL Express that stores the data for it, which is also teeny tiny. I'm not sure about ports, but I was curious about HTTP Keep-Alive from the web browsers, I'm not sure if it's relavent

Comment: I also just confirmed that this is an issue even if I try to download the file directly from the root of IIS (not from our Web Api), we still get the network error, so I don't think this has to do with our code or services now.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I finally did, after much much research and toying with changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to finally fix our problem. For us it turned out to be a combination of two things: 1) we had several memory leaks and CPU intensive code in our Web Api that was impacting concurrent downloads, and 2) we ultimately resolved the issue by changing MinBytesPerSecond (see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2013/02/01/its-not-iis/) to a lower value, or 0 to disable. We have not had an issue since.